# getting object not found error after clicking submit button, I want to display the value of hidden tag

Tags: php, html

```
<html>
<BODY>
    <form   action= "myscript.php" method="post">
        first name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mary"><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value= "clan"><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mychoices[]" value="choice1" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mychoices[]" value="choice2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="mychoices[]" value="choice3">
        <select name="myselection">
        <option value="selection1" selected>Option1</option>
        <option value="selection2">Option2</option>
        <option value="selection3">Option3</option>
        </select>
        <select name="myselections[]" size="3" multiple>
        <option value="choice1" selected >Choice1</option>
        <option value="choice2" selected>choice2</option>
        <option value="choice3">choice3</option>
        </select>
        <textarea name="mytextarea" rows="10" cols="40">
        Welcome to the web developement world.
        </textarea>
        <input type="password" name="mypassword">
        <input type="hidden" name="myname" value = "myvalue">
        <input type="reset" value="reset form">
        <input type="image" name="myimage" src="desert.jpg" height="42" width="42" onclick= "document.write('<? php Aftersubmit() ?>');"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Submit Form">

    </form>

<?php
        function Aftersubmit()
    {
        $myname = $_POST['myname'];
        if(isset($myname)){
        echo ($myname);

        }
    }

?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I want to display the value of hidden tag after clicking submit button. But getting "Object not found" error 404. Beginner in php, pls help. I also want to know how to call php functions from html.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a PHP function from an onClick event. That only works with Javascript functions. So one problem is in this line:

```
onclick= "document.write('<? php Aftersubmit() ?>');
```

You can remove that, and then pull your PHP out of the function. This will display your name if you click the submit button.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submitbutton'])){
    $myname = $_POST['myname'];

    if(isset($myname)){
        echo ($myname);
    }
}

?>
```

You may also have to change the action of your form:

```
<form   action= "myscript.php" method="post">
```

If the file myscript.php doesn't exist, then you'll get a 404 Not Found error every time. You can make a form point to itself by removing the action attribute:

```
<form method="post">
```